# A Swift timer declared as a class variable doesn't call the selector

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I need to be able to invalidate and restart a timer from a couple of different functions.

In order to do this, I think I need to create my timer as a class variable.

When I created the timer in the local scope of a function, it worked fine, but I couldn't invalidate it from other functions.

However, when I moved it to a variable defined at the class level with the type: Timer, it fails to call the selector function. I don't get any errors.

I have this in viewDidAppear:

```
self.timer? = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(UploadViewController.readFromBean), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Here is how my selector is set up:

```
func readFromBean(){
    print("reading from bean")
    if myBean != nil{
        myBean?.readAccelerationAxes()
        myBean?.readTemperature()
        myBean?.readScratchBank(1)
        myBean?.readScratchBank(2)
        myBean?.readScratchBank(3)
        myBean?.readScratchBank(4)
        myBean?.readScratchBank(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `self.timer? = ...` instead of just `self.timer = ...` ? And why `if myBean != nil {` followed by all of the `myBean?.read...` references instead of `if let myBean = MyBean {` following by `myBean.read...`

Comment: The honest answer is that I am still learning the syntax, and I don't always know the most efficient way to write what I'm trying to do. These statements shouldn't be the cause of my problem though, right?

Comment: Hmmm... I removed the ? and it seems to have solved the problem. If you want to post that as a solution, I will mark it correct.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Consider to use a singleton class and instance methods for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you liked one of the comments, but thought I'd share the strategy I have used successfully.  In this case, the `Timer` is in the `AppDelegate`.

The class looks like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    // lots of stuff removed 
    var loadOrdersTimer: Timer?

    // ... blah blah ... application specific methods

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        if let loadOrdersTimer = self.loadOrdersTimer? {
            loadOrdersTimer.invalidate()
            self.loadOrdersTimer = nil
        }
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        setOrderLoadingTimer()
    }

    func setOrderLoadingTimer() {
        self.loadOrdersTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: intervalSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loadOrders), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func loadOrders() {
        // do the work for which the Timer was scheduled
    }

}
```